# Android Management API Delegate scope PACKAGE_ACCESS setPackageSuspended admin null?

Tags: android, android-management-api

I'm trying to make a companion app for disable not used packages. Device is in "fully managed device mode" an my app has delegated scope for PACKAGE_ACCESS.
Acording to Googles documentation [PACKAGE_ACCESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#DELEGATION_PACKAGE_ACCESS) this give access to setPackagesSuspended(ComponentName, String[], boolean).

But when you read documentation for [setPackagesSuspended](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setPackagesSuspended(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean)) it says:

| Parameters | Description |
| --- | --- |
| admin: ComponentName | The name of the admin component to check, **or null if the caller is a package access delegate**. **This value cannot be null**. |
| packageNames: String | The package names to suspend or unsuspend. This value cannot be null. |
| suspended: boolean | If set to true than the packages will be suspended, if set to false the packages will be unsuspended. |

My app is a package access delegate and I shoud use null as admin, but compiler don't let me use null.

When I try:

```
dpm.getDelegatedScopes(null, "my app package name")
```

I get:
delegation-permission-grant, delegation-enable-system-app, delegation-block-uninstall, delegation-package-access

I have tryed:

Not compiling:

```
var dpm = mContext.getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
dpm.setPackagesSuspended(null, arrayOf("packageName to suspend"), true)
```

Compiling but getting a runtime error:

```
var dpm = mContext.getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
dpm.setPackagesSuspended(null as ComponentName, arrayOf("packageName to suspend"), true)
```

Getting error

```
var dpm = mContext.getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
dpm.setPackagesSuspended(dpm.activeAdmins!![0], arrayOf("packageName to suspend"), true)
```

Admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver} is not owned by uid 10255

How can I use setPackagesSuspended()?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in Kotlin (or at least I don't know how) but in Java you can just use null for admin param and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).